# Has my unique index been set?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying set a composite unique index made of 2 fields using:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD UNIQUE INDEX(location,duplicate_count)
```

when I check under indexes in phpmyadmin I see:

```
Keyname Type    Unique  Packed  Column  Cardinality Collation   Null    Comment
PRIMARY BTREE   Yes No  id  1   A   No  
location    BTREE   Yes No     location 1   A   Yes 
                               duplicate_count1 A   Yes
```

So it looks like ( If I understand correctly ) that there is 1 index, a composite index called location made of 2 fields ( location and duplicate_count ). If this is correct that is what I am trying to do. Does my explanation seem correct?

thanks in advance,

Bill

Comment: You're created a composite unique index called location made up of fields location and duplicate_count1.

Comment: unique is yes, both fields are showing up, so yep.. it worked. you can always test it yourself... try to insert the same two values into that field twice.

Comment: Short answer: Yes. Long answer: Also yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your explanation is correct. Try to insert the same values twice, as @MarcB suggested. If phpmyadmin/mysql console blames you, then it's ok.